# Call to zmq_socket returns NULL and errno 14 (Bad address)

Tags: c, zeromq

I am working on a test client/server application using ZeroMQ x86 for connectivity on Windows 8, VS 2012. Unfortunately, I have some trouble with initializing a connection. For now I simply copied (and slightly extended with error reporting) the example [hwserver.c](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Ask-and-Ye-Shall-Receive) and use following code to initialize:

```
void* ctx;
void* rsp;
ctx = zmq_ctx_new();
DWORD dwErr = zmq_errno();
printf("Creating Context - %s\r\n", zmq_strerror(dwErr));

rsp = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_REP);
dwErr = zmq_errno();
printf("Creating Socket - %s\r\n", zmq_strerror(dwErr));
```

This fails at the call to `zmq_socket` which returns `rsp == NULL` and `dwErr==14`: Bad address. Given that this is nearly identical to the example code and yet it fails I'm out of answers. Maybe someone has an idea what is wrong with that call. Maybe it is a compatibility issue with using 32bit binaries?

Comment: Have you, @antipattern, checked the remarks on **building 64-bit binaries** as in >>> http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2010-June/004037.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't think however, that this applies here because I am using prebuild binaries and also, I explicitly link against the 32bit binaries (my application dictates that, it is not compatible to a 64bit build)

Comment: Have you tried copying and running the code from the example with no modifications at all?

Comment: Yes, initially I started with unmodified code, which does not report the errors however. There it simply asserts when the bind fails. And similar to my post, `responder==NULL`

Comment: What version of zmq are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue when I accidentally installed an old version of libzmq on my system. Once I removed it and installed a newer version, the problem went away.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that this is not an answer to my question. With hindsight to my original issue, It was _exactly_ what had happened.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a good amount of debugging and trying to reproduce the error in new Projects, i've come up with following solution:

`libzmq.lib` has to be the first entry of all the .lib's that are about to be linked vs. the project.